# Arzelà–Ascoli theorem for operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, operator-algebras, locally-convex-spaces

If you have a net of continuous linear operators between reasonable spaces (complete, at least), does there exist Arzelà–Ascoli-like theorems giving convergent subnets? I believe that it should be related in spirit to the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, but I don't recall having ever seen such result.

Comment: There are several possible topologies on the space of linear operators.  Which do you want to use?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle and the first corollary: "Note it is not claimed above that Tn converges to T in operator norm, i.e. uniformly on bounded sets. (However, since {Tn} is bounded in operator norm, and the limit operator T is continuous, a standard "3-ε" estimate shows that Tn converges to T uniformly on compact sets.)"

Comment: @NateEldredge: I am not interested in any fancy mode of convergence. On the other hand, I am quite free in choosing the topology that suits me best (this is a small research project), so I think I'll stick with the three basic ones: operator norm topology, strong operator topology and weak operator topology.

Comment: For the weak operator topology, any net that is bounded in operator norm has a convergent subnet (i.e. norm-bounded sets are WOT relatively compact).  Is that the kind of thing you want?  The proof is basically the same as Banach-Alaoglu.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, that one is already very good. Since you haven't mentioned them, I guess that you don't know anything useful concerning the other two topologies. If you can detail your comment (maybe add a bibliographic reference), you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I am only familiar with te weak operator topology in Hilbert spaces. But in general, it is probably the topology generated by $A \mapsto \phi(Ax)$ with $x$ in the domain and $\phi$ in the dual of the codomain of $A$. In this case, your claim will only be true (I think) if the codomain is reflexive. Otherwise, consider $A_n : \Bbb{R}\to X,a \mapsto a x_n$, where $(x_n)_n$ has no weakly convergent subsequence (which can exist e.g. in $L^1=X$).

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes, you're right, I was also thinking of Hilbert space and didn't read the tags carefully.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Should I understand, then, that at least for Hilbert spaces Nate Eldridge's version remains true?